# Unblocking Downloads in Chromium for Windows (Turning off File Zone Security)

Tags: google-chrome, download, chromium

Is there any way to prevent my downloads from getting file zone security information?

[image]

Blocking executables is already very annoying (I know quite well what I'm doing), and it really ticks me off that even CSV files are blocked for "security" reasons!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome now respects the Windows setting for zone identifiers and can be configured as shown below.

### Global attachment policy

You can change how Windows handles zone identifiers using the group policy editor (`gpedit.msc`); the location of these settings is `User Configuration` -> `Administrative Templates` -> `Windows Components` -> `Attachment Manager`.

`Do not preserve zone information in file attachments` was implemented in Chrome as of April 29, 2011 (see [Issue 5719](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5719)).

Changing the default risk of attachments* to low will deactivate the dialog completely and ignore a file's zone security information.

Additionally, you can specify exceptions for certain file extension to, for example, always ask when opening downloaded `.exe` files.

### Delete zone settings from the command line

If you only want to remove the zone settings from certain files, you can use `streams.exe` from the [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) to delete all alternate NTFS data streams:

`streams -d <file>` and
`streams -s -d <directory>`

`:Zone.Identifier` is the stream used to store zone security information.

#### Sources

[chromium - Issue 5719: SetInternetZoneIdentifier does not respect the SaveZoneInformation policy](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5719)
[msigeek.com - How to Remove Security Warning Message – Files Downloaded from Internet](http://www.msigeek.com/6220/how-to-remove-security-warning-message-files-downloaded-from-internet)

Comment: * I'm using the German version of Windows Vista, so the actual name of the setting may be different. For me it says "Standardrisikostufe für Dateianlagen".

Comment: I'm already aware of both methods, but the question was specifically about Chrome, and specifically about *preventing* it from embedding file zone information in the first place. Thanks for the help, but this doesn't do what I was asking. :\

Comment: Well, you could always download the chromium source and remove the call to `SetInternetZoneIdentifier` in `chrome\common\win_safe_util.cc`, then use that a custom build without automatic updates. Another way would be to use `IAttachmentExecute::SetLocalPath` and `IAttachmentExecute::Save`, submitting it as patch to the project and to wait until it is committed to Chrome's release channel. If you want a faster solution, you can also create a new FAT32 partition and mount it into your download folder. As FAT32 doesn't support ADS, the zone information is never written.

Comment: You said in your question that Chrome's behavior was "annoying", so I figured you would be satisfied with an easier, more flexible and at the same time more specific solution (not blocking .csv files).

Comment: @Tamschi: I tried the custom build route (on a locally mounted VHD, since I wasn't about to add 400,000 files to my drives), but I couldn't get the build working... it's too much of a pain. And obviously the FAT32 solution is more of a problem than a solution. :( Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Yea, that happened with just about half of the source codes I tried to compile... Most often there's some not included dependency or a crazy prerequisite that messes up half of my system. Using Windows probably doesn't help either when building these cross-platform programs.

Comment: Just setting the default to low was not enough in my case. I had to add ".exe" to **Inclusion list for low file types**