# Open File - Security Warning when downloading files with Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-explorer

When I download an executable file using Google Chrome and I want to open it, this appears:

[image]

I don't want this to be displayed each and every time, because I know that an executable file "can potentially harm my computer".

**Question:** How do I disable this in Google Chrome?

(I know it can be done in Firefox using about:config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually windows telling you this. If you right-click on the file, go to Properties, then hit the Unblock button at the bottom of the property window.

Because the file was an unsigned (essentially an unknown exe) downloaded from the internet, it was marked by Windows as a potentially unsafe file.

According to [Unblocking Downloads in Chromium for Windows (Turning off File Zone Security)](https://superuser.com/questions/247647/unblocking-downloads-in-chromium-for-windows-turning-off-file-zone-security) Chrome doesn't have the ability to automatically remove this unsafe file flag. Firefox is probably doing it for you.

There are ways to disable it in the entire OS I believe, you can search and easily find that information.

Comment: Okay, so chrome doesn't have this option. But now I know that there is an unlock button and I don't have to execute the file to unlock it. Thanks for that :)